# size(int x, int y) running but not working in intellij after building processing library path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, buildpath

So basically, I'm at avid user of openframeworks which uses c++, but I have an upcoming project in school which requires for me to use java, so I plan on using processing for this in the intellij IDEA. I followed a few tutorials on how to add the core.jar file to a project in intellij, and everything worked well (so far), except size(int x, int y) doesn't do anything to the canvas. This also makes me wonder what other functions might not work properly. Is there anything else I need to add to the class path?

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Main extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("Main");
    }

    public void setting(){
        size(500,500);
    }

    public void setup(){
        background(100,100,100);
    }

    public void draw(){
        line(50,50,70,70);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setting()
```

is misspelled. The correct signature is:

```
public void settings()
```

To avoid problems like this, you can use the `@Override` annotation:

```
@Override
public void settings()
```

The compiler will warn you if you try to override a method that does not exist in the super class.